# Unable to sign a Windows app on macOS/Linux with Electron-builder

Tags: electron, code-signing, electron-builder, code-signing-certificate

I am using Monterey 12.3.1 and following this instructions:
https://www.electron.build/tutorials/code-signing-windows-apps-on-unix

I am trying to sign with osslsigncode. I am failing at this step:

11. Install token driver for Mac, export the certificate (convert it to pem when it is .cer)

**1. What is actually the token driver? Where to obtain it?**

**2. I received 2 .cer files from my customer. When I export them from my keychain .pem and .cer is the same content. Is that right?**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGzTCCBLWg...etc
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Also further down:

13. Figure out the key ID by running pkcs11-tool --module /usr/local/lib/libeTPkcs11.dylib -l -O

/usr/local/lib/libeTPkcs11.dylib is missing on my system. Where does it come from? I installed libp11 like stated in the tutorial but this lib is not built. I only have a libpkcs11.dylib but it does not seem to work.

**Where I am getting libeTPkcs11.dylib from?** Google does not help me here..

I am a total noob in this code signing game. So every help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One key thing to understand in those instructions is that they are only needed if you are using an EV code signing certificate, in which case your code signing key will be stored on a hardware token (plugs into a USB port). If you aren't using that then you don't need to worry about it.

If you are using an EV certificate then the token driver is the driver for the hardware token containing your key and the driver comes from wherever you got the token -- and the libetpkcs11.dylib is one example of what the driver might be.